# iframe 100% height not applying

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, height

I have a site with master pages and the only thing I want on one page is this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe src="http://mylink" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

The width of the iframe does expand to the width of the screen but the height is always something like 100 pixels even though it should be close to 1050.

Browser IE9. How to fix the height problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying a height of 100% to an element only works if the parent element has a specific height  already applied to it.

For example:

```
<div style="height:500px">
  <iframe style="height:100%;">I am 500px too!</iframe>
</div>
```

If your goal is to have the iframe take up the width and height of the viewport, you need to set the following in your stylesheet:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

<s>You will also need to add a 100% height for all ancestor elements of the iframe. So, if it is 5 `<div>`s deep, each of those divs needs 100% height.</s> **EDIT**: This does not appear to be the case, at least in Chrome. Though at least one ancestor element does need a specific height set.

**EDIT:** Here is a jsfiddle link as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/V3rLE/

The HTML is:

```
<div style="height:100%">
<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;border:0" src="http://jsfiddle.net"></iframe>
</div>​
```

The CSS is:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
iframe { display: block; }
```

Comment: Have tried setting .page, body, html to 100%, nothing. It works fine if I set it a predefined siz ein pixels but the point is to take the height of the screen for different resolutions. and the below does not wor for some reason: `<asp:HiddenField ID="hfScreenWidth" runat="server" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    /*Send the current screen resolution width to the C# code*/
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= hfScreenWidth.ClientID %>').val(screen.width);
    });` well the screen.width is correct but the hiddenfield is always empty.

Comment: Is there perhaps an element between the iframe and the body and html elements which has a specific height set, or perhaps has some other CSS property like float that might be causing the browser to calculate height differently? I would use something like Chrome Developer tools (or equivalent in other browsers) to inspect each ancestor element and play with the CSS properties until you figure out what is happening. Also, make sure you're in standards mode with a proper DOCTYPE, as Quirks Mode might cause different behaviors.

Comment: yeah I'll just set it manually for now and get back to it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want set height=100% .It will take as content height ...suppose you have only one gridview.consider gridview height as 200px..the page height also 200px only...so try to use height in pixel.